# Cannot generate Phoenix app on Windows

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm having serious trouble with using Elixir's Phoenix Framework on Windows8. After getting past most of the platform specific bugs an error tells me that rebar cannot be found and did not compile ranch. I've even gone as far as putting rebar in my enviroment path but its still complaining. All in all, what should I do to compile ranch, there is an example of the error below.

```
Programming PC@PROGRAMMING-PC ~/Documents/GitHub/Elixir/phoenix ((v0.6.1))
$mix phoenix.new newapp ~/newapp
'c:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
←[31m←[1m** (Mix) Could not compile dependency ranch, c:/Program Files/rebar/reb
ar.cmd command failed. If you want to recompile this dependency, please run: mix
 deps.compile ranch←[0m
```

Comment: The part `'c:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command` suggests that something is not happy with the space in the path to `rebar`. Maybe you could try to put it somewhere else, in a path that contains no spaces as a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks I your comment helped lead me to the solution as well. If you don't mind could you upvote my question or my answer? I need points so that I can start upvoting people. Not to mention I am sure that there are other devs on Windows who may encounter this irritating bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) Make sure you've got rebar in your path.

2.) As @p11y pointed out above, it looks like it's unhappy with the space in the directory name.  The simplest fix is to look up the [short name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) equivalent of the path and use that instead.  And the easiest way to do that is to use the `dir /x` command from a command prompt to find out what the equivalent 8.3 name is.

3.) Looking at the prompt above--are you using Cygwin or Mingw32?  If so, the path may be different.  Make sure you can navigate to the `C:/program files/rebar` path in the shell you're using.

Comment: No, I'm using Git Bash I probably should have specified that sorry about that. Yes, you and **@p11y** were right it was the space in `Program Files`. The problem was fixed by using `Program Files` alternative name `PROGRA~1`, thank you. BTW could you upvote my question so that other devs on windows8 can see (and so I can get points to upvote people)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the others the error was caused by a Windows gotcha in my path to `rebar`. Normally this doesn't cause me any trouble but in this the space in `C:/Program Files/rebar` was the problem. In order to fix this error I had to replace `Program Files` with its alias `PROGRA~1`, which doesn't have a space. After doing this everything compiled without a problem.